# looking for activity Recognition algorithm or resource

Tags: artificial-intelligence, vision, activity-recognition

i am implementing a surveillance system and i was looking for algorithm or any resource that could help me with activity Recognition.  activity like punch, kick and etc. so when someone kick or punch in a record video the system could recognize that activity.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is too broad and off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Human activity/action recognition is one of the hottest topics in ML.

There are challenges like THUMOS, Activity-Net, UCF-101 where this topic is widely studied.

Some of the winners of these challenges have released their codes, you can take a look at them. They have also given how to train our own network with custom dataset and labels. If you don't find the actions that you require in that list, you can build a dataset and train their networks on it.

[CUHK](https://github.com/yjxiong/anet2016-cuhk)

[Activity Localisation](https://github.com/imatge-upc/activitynet-2016-cvprw)